# what is the meaning of this line do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Home?

Tags: html, jsp

I am looking at a sample jsp project. Can you explain this line:
`do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Home`

Here is the full code:

```
<div id="ddblueblockmenu">
      <div class="menutitle">&nbsp;Fleet Profiles</div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Home">MyHome</a></li>
            <%
            if(uname != null) {
            %>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Home">Welcome <%= uname %></a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=uEdit">Edit Details</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Logout">LogOut</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=bokUser">Booking Details</a></li>
            <%}else {%>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Reg">Register Now</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Login">Login Now</a></li>
            <% } %>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Car">Take a Car Trip</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=View&v=lux">Luxury Cars</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=View&v=exe">Executive Cars</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=View&v=muv">MUV's & SUV's</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=View&v=eco">Economy Cars</a></li>
            <li><a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=View&v=mini">Mini Vans & Large Coaches</a></li>         
          </ul>
          <div class="menutitle">&nbsp;</div>   
    </div>
```

Comment: do - is the name of the script which will process request when somebody click on link

Comment: ?MOD=BOK&ACT=Car - parameters which will send to the do script

Comment: When the link is clicked you will navigate to `do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Home` which will define the POST variables MOD and ACT. These can then be used in your backend in order to load a different page loadd imagine.

Comment: @JonathanBartlett: These are not POST variables, by default href links send a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Home">MyHome</a>
```

Here  is anchor tag for hypertext referencing. and in its href property value is `"do?MOD=BOK&ACT=Home"`. In this value do is some other resource related mapping. MOD is first request parameter and the value of this request parameter is "BOK" while ACT is second request parameter and the value of this parameter is HOME.
When a user clicks on this link:

1. An http request is generated(By default href link generates GET request only) and control is going to the server
2. The control comes to the servlet container
3. Servlet container observes the mapped url "do"
4. Selvlet container seeks in web.xml for any available url-mapping with "do"
   For example say:

`<servlet-mapping>`

```
`<servlet-name>`DemoServlet`</servlet-name>`

`<url-pattern>`/do`</url-pattern>`
```

`</servlet-mapping>`

5. If it gets any such url-mapping in web.xml, the control goes to the mapped servlet class(In above example control goes to the DemoServlet class)
6. If no such mapping is available in web.xml, user gets 404 error that means resource not found.
7. If mapped resource is available and control goes to the DemoServlet, our two request parameters are available there and their values can be accessed as:

   request.getParameter("MOD")
   &
   request.getParameter("ACT")